It was the second, but we were told it was the fifth
Can you determine the meaning of this rebus?


I would even say it’s too easy!

@PierrePaquette Sometimes my puzzles are easy and sometimes they are tough.  Sometimes I receive positive comments on my easy puzzles like, Finally a puzzle that I can solve.  Please keep in mind that people vary in their puzzle solving skills.

Oh, absolutely! :) And while it was easy for me, it may not be easy for someone who isn’t into movies. I find a lot of the puzzles here require knowledge of other stuff—I have seen some that are impossible to solve if you don’t know history, for example, or flags, or wine, or…

@Will.Octagon.Gibson I believe Pierre meant to say that it was "all too easy" ;)

I think the answer is

 Star Wars Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back

Image:

 The word "Empire" striked out and rendered backwards.

Title:

 "[I]t is the second film in the Star Wars film series and the fifth chronological chapter of the 'Skywalker Saga'." (from Wikipedia)

